# Is that possible to test Person Account in an Org with Person Account disabled?

Tags: apex, unit-test, person-accounts

Currently working on a managed app and have code acting differently depending on if PersonAccount in a client's org is enabled or not.
Is there a way to cover the PersonAccount-related apex code with tests in an org which has PersonAccount disabled (the org where the app is developed)?

So basically I'm checking if PersonAccount is enabled using this:

```
Schema.sObjectType.Account.fields.getMap().containsKey('isPersonAccount')
```

It's returning false because it's not enabled.
But I also need to get the opposite outcome covered with tests.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to enable it to test it.  I presume it's similar to State Country Picklist, where StateCode/CountryCode fields only appear when SCP is enabled, and disappear when you disable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a private static variable annotated with [`@TestVisible`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_testvisible.htm) then provide a public method that return whether the person account is active checking if that variable has been set, if so the method returns its value, otherwise the method returns you current check:

```java
@TestVisible
private static Boolean testPersonAccountStatus;

private static Boolean orgPersonAccountStatus = Schema.sObjectType.Account.fields.getMap().containsKey('isPersonAccount');

public static Boolean isPersonAccountActive() {
    return testPersonAccountStatus != null ? testPersonAccountStatus : orgPersonAccountStatus;
}
```

Then in you test method you're going to set that variable according to the use case you want to test.
This way your test will not depends upon the org status and you will be able to cover both scenario.

By the way, `private` keywork isn't mandatory since it's the default, but it may be used to let other developers knows your intent avoiding misunderstanding.

Comment: Works for me, thanks!